# how to mock class in java without creating interface

Tags: java, testing, mocking

First, I am not Java developer, I am using php.

I am curious in Java, for example if I have structure like this:

```
interface Ainterface {
    public String method();
}

public class A implements Ainterface {
    public String method() {
       //do something
    }
}

public class B {
    public String method(Ainterface a) {
       a.method();
       //do something
    }
}
```

Now if I want to test `B`'s method I can mock `a`

```
public class Amock implements Ainterface {
    public String method() {
       //do something
    }
}
```

And inject it into `B`'s method.

But, if I don't want to create interface and I have situation like this:

```
public class A {
    public String method() {
       //do something
    }
}

public class B {
    public String method(A a) {
       a.method();
       //do something
    }
}
```

Is there any way to mock `a` or test `B`'s method in other way?

Answer (score 4):

In Java you can use specific mocking framework like [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) and use it's specific method - for example

```
A aMock = Mockito.mock(A.class);
```

Of course this way you can only create a really simple mock that will do literally nothing but the framework allows you to define what specific method should return with providing `when/then` mechanism. The example of such can be

```
when(aMock.method()).thenReturn("I am just a fake");
```

The mockito is really powerfull and I cannot explain you whole framework in this answer so please visit Mockito home and [reference](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html) page to get familiar with this

Also Mockito is one of solutions - it's kind of popular but not only the one so you can look for the solution that fits your requirements best

Comment: Thanks for answer, I get that, but if I don't want to use some framework is there any native way?

Comment: Yes, but that would be reinventing the wheel, producing code to do something similar that mockito does. (Building your own mocking framework, for example with Proxies)

Comment: Building your own mocking framework is not a native way

Answer (score 1):

@m.antkowicz's answer shows the correct way of doing it, by using a mocking framework. In the comments you asked for a way without using external framework, so this answer tries to address that.

Just like you created `Amock` by *implementing* `Ainterface`, you can create a child class that *extends* `A`.

So you would have a class like `class AmockClassBased extends A` and then you can **override** `method()` to make it do what you were doing in `Amock` class's `method()`.

So your `Amock` will be changed to:-

```
public class AmockClassBased extends A {

    @Override
    public String method() {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Then you can pass an instance of this class to `B`'s `method(A a)`.